# delete an element from a Hierarichal object in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jsonarray like this

```
var MAinobj = 
{
{
Name:"iteration1",
Parent:null
},
{
Name:"iteration2",
Parent:null
},
{
Name:"iteration3",
Parent:"null"
},
{
Name:"step2",
Parent:"iteration1"
},
{
Name:"step3",
Parent:"iteration2"
},
{
Name:"step4",
Parent:"iteraton3"
},
{
Name:"task1",
Parent:"step3"
},
{
Name:"task2",
Parent:"step3"
},
}
```

I want is my json array look like this. I will give the name like iteration2  then I need to delete all its childrens and subchildrens also means after deleting my json object look like this:

```
var Mainobj = 
{
{
Name:"iteration1",
Parent:null
},
{
Name:"iteration3",
Parent:null
},
{
Name:"step2",
Parent:"iteration1"
},
{
Name:"step4",
Parent:"iteration3"
}
}
```

I want my json object look like this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

First, json arrays are enveloped by [] not {}. If you want an object instead, you should give a name to each element, like this:

```
var mainObj = {
    "step2": {...},
    "step3": {...}
}
```

You might want to look into [recursion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx). You can create a function that searches all elements in an array that have a certain parent. Before deleting each element, you call the function, passing the found child-element.

Something like this:

```
function removeTree(list, parentName){
    var index = 0;
    while (index < list.length){ // The list length will change with each element removed
        var elem = list[index];

        if (elem.Name === parentName){ // "parent" found
            list.splice(index,1); // Remove the current element
        } else if (elem.Parent === parentName) { // "child" found
            list.splice(index,1); // Remove the current element
            removeTree(list, elem.Name); // Remove all its children
        } else {
            index++; // If this element isn't a child of parentName, look at the next one
        }
    }
};
```